# Samba does not create homedirs automatically

Tags: samba, pam

All shares on the samba server are accessible except the homes share.
The operating system is Ubuntu 18.04.
I have enabled pam_mkhomedir in /etc/pam.d/samba

Connecting to the homes share of user "administrator" makes smbd log this error:

> canonicalize_connect_path failed for service administrator,

Is there anything I've forgotten to configure?

Answer (score 0):

in /etc/samba/smb.conf has to be the following parameter:

```
obey pam restrictions = yes
```